# Detecting browser with protractor

Tags: node.js, protractor

Is there a way to detect the browser testing my scripts in protractor? Looked everywhere! I'm trying to factor all my different browser specs into one each so that in the config file I simply change the browser name and execute the same script.  I've already tried these;

`if (isFirefox)`

`if (browser === 'firefox')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you set the browser through the `capabilities` object right?

You can get the browser that you set here in your test script with

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function (capabilities) {
  browserName = capabilities.get('browserName');
});
```

Now just check this variable.

Comment: I did that and called `if (browser.browserName === 'firefox'){
            console.log('im here');
            browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
        }` but it runs over that code

Comment: Does `browser.browserName` get at least set in the promise?

Comment: Removing `browser` from `browser.browserName` fixed everything. Thanks for the input. Much appreciated.

Comment: Also had to change to `browserName = capabilities.get('browserName');` from `browserName = capabilities.caps_.browserName;`. Think latter is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just directly accessing the `capabilities` browserName?

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': (process.env.TEST_BROWSER_NAME || 'firefox')
    , 'version': (process.env.TEST_BROWSER_VERSION || 'ANY')
 },

if(capabilities.browserName === 'firefox') {
//do something here
}
```

In case of `multiCapabilities`

```
  multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'chrome'
 }, {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
 }],
```

you could try something like this

```
if(multiCapabilities[0].browserName === 'firefox') {
//do something here
}
if(multiCapabilities[1].browserName === 'chrome') {
//do something here
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this code!

Comment: Removing `browser` from `browser.browserName` did fix it from @KRONWALLED's answer. I think yours should work too. Thanks.